# delete numbers in array between 6 and the following 7

Tags: arrays

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers. 
This is a coding bat problem.

I was thinking of using arrays.toList, that will make things complicated.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code will ignore all array elements between an array element '6' to the next element '7', including the  '6' and '7' (they'll be ignored too);

```
bool ignore = false;
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == 6)
        ignore = true;
    if(!ignore)
        sum+= arr[i];
    if(arr[i] == 7)
        ignore = false;

}
```